# My posts page get doubled. Rails, ajax, jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I added ajax to my rails blog. It worked with only one post, but something weird is going on after I added next. I get copies of my posts on this same page.

**Comments_controller.rb**

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @posts = Post.all
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to @post}
            format.js
        end
    end

end
```

## index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'post' %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
  $('.post').html("<%= escape_javascript(render("posts/post")) %>") });
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="post">
            <p><strong> <%= post.title %> </strong>, posted <%= post.created_at.to_date %> </p> <br />
            <%= post.content %> <br />

            <%= simple_form_for [post, post.comments.build], :remote => true do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :content %>
                <%= f.button :submit %>
            <% end %>

            <%= render :partial => 'comment', :locals => {:post => post} %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div class = "comment">
  <ol>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <li> <%= comment.content %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the `show.html.erb` view for your post (due to the `redirect_to @post`), the answer should be clear then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

be there? If you're just displaying the post for one page, you could simply access the properties outside of the block using `@post`. If this isn't it, I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: there are multiple posts on this page. It's index page.

Comment: Then I'm misunderstanding your question. What is it that you're trying to do?